# MVC Web Api Differentiate between user and public data in RESTful approach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api2

When it comes down to good RESTfull setup, what is the best practice for providing results that pertain to the owner as the requestor and results that pertain to a user wanting data owned by another user.

I have read that a resource should have max 2 base URLs so how to handle say,
Get all items for authenticated user
Get a single item for Authenticated user
Get all items for a particular user
Get a single item for a particular user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question is a bit unclear, it seems to me you might mix up "Resources" as in HTTP resources, and Model objects or database rows.

The two do not necessarily have a 1-to-1 relationship, or even 1-to-2 relationship as you seem to imply. You can expose a database row in multiple "forms" as resources, there is no limitation how many times you can aggregate, transform or publish the same information, as long as those are all semantically different things.

So, back to your problem. You can publish resources pertaining to the authenticated user, and just users independently which might also contain the current user. With an URI structure for example like this:

```
/currentuser
/user/1
/user/2  <- might be the same as /currentuser
/user/3
...
```

There also could be a list of users recently logged in:

```
/recentuser/444
/recentuser/445  <- might be again /currentuser
...
```

That would be a third reference on the same user, but it is ok, because all of those have a different meaning, might even have different representations to offer (one might offer more information than others).